# Случайно составил Google календарь на часовом поясе GMT+0... Как все мероприятия сдвинуть, чтобы было нормально на GMT+5?

Tags: python, calendar, google-calendar, google-calendar-api

2 часа потратил на то, чтобы составить календарь. Захожу с телефона, а там часовой пояс GMT+5 и все мои события сдвинуты на 5 часов вперёд.
Писал скрипты, Google Calendar API активировал и пробовал всякое 4 часа, лишь бы сдвинуть мое расписание и не переделывать каждый элемент по отдельности.

И ничего не помогало, всякие ошибки и т.д.

Что мне теперь делать? Как расписание назад сдвинуть на 5 часов, чтобы когда я выбирал GMT+5 все нормально было?

Comment: Ну поставь телефон на GMT+0

Comment: Тогда время в календаре будет показываться неправильно и уведомления должным образом работать не будут